# basic question difference between @ in active record

Tags: ruby

I have a basic question that I can not understand yet from ruby. If in active record, I have "@food" , how does it differ with "food". I recogn it is an array, but aren"t the active record can be assumes as a list of datas (array?)

Thanks for the sharing

Comment: I recommend you read a bit about Ruby itself, before you dive into Rails. You seem to be confused about where the basic concepts belong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with ActiveRecord. It is just plain Ruby syntax.

`@foo` denotes an instance variable. It is scoped to the instance of its class, and is different for every instance of the class. The contents are kept as long as the class instance is kept.

`foo` may denote a local variable, which is valid only in the current block scope. It goes out of scope as soon as the block exits, and the contents are discarded unless referenced elsewhere.

And the @ notation has nothing to do with arrays or any other data type. In Ruby, variables don't have data types. `@bar` will readily accept a string, integer or array without complaint. And so will `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

A `@var` means a variable with its scope in an instance of a model.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Instance_Variables